# django jquery scrolling does not activate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have a jquery function that works when I run that as an event, but does not work when I try to get it to run when the document reloads.

This is my element for the window to scroll to when the page refreshes.

```
{% block content %}
  {% for poll in polls %}

    <button class="test" id="{{ poll.id }}">{{ poll.id }}</button>

  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This code below works fine, it's attached to a click event.

```
{% block jquery %}
{#  <script>#}

testEvent();

  // sending the poll id to report after the flag is clicked on
  function testEvent() {
    $(".test").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      var scrolltoid = document.getElementById('54')
      scrolltoid.scrollIntoView(true);
      window.scrollBy(0, -50);

    });
  };

{#  </script>#}
{% endblock %}
```

I need the code to work when the page refreshes. However, when the same code is inserted into document ready function to scroll the window to the specific element when the page refreshes, it is not working.

```
{% block jquery %}
{#  <script>#}


$(document).ready(function(){
    var scrolltoid = document.getElementById('54')
    scrolltoid.scrollIntoView(false);
})


{#  </script>#}
{% endblock %}
```

I also tried running the alternative code below. I saw the scroll successful very quickly for just a split second, but when the page completely refreshes, my window scrolls back to the top again instead of shifting to the element id.

```
{% block jquery %}
{#  <script>#}
  $(document).ready(function () {
      // Handler for .ready() called.
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#54').offset().top
      }, 'slow');
  });
{#  </script>#}
{% endblock %}
```

This code was left over by a previous programmer and I am confused about the usage of {#  #}. I think the reason my code wouldnt work might be because of the {#  #} that was included. I am very confused as to its usage, if I remove the comment, all the jquery/javascript on the page would stop running, so I couldn't remove it. But this confuses me because {# #} is for commenting out code on django, and what is commented out should not impact the code itself, but the {#  #} tag in my code is required to get all the script on my page to work (except it doesn't work with scroll when page refreshes). I have tried doing research on {# #} but havent found anything useful on it.

Comment: wrt/ the commented "script" tags: your template extends another one, which obviously already have the opening and closing "script" tags - as you could have found out by [reading the manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance).

Comment: Actually the script tags to extend one template into another is using "%" - {% block content %}, while the script tags i have questions about is using "#", which is used to comment out code as described by the document.

Comment: I know django template language thx. Please re-read my previous comment, then check the parent(s) template(s) until you find the initial declaration of the `jquery` block. You can be sure the html `script` tags will be there _around_ the block. Which is why uncommenting them in your child template breaks all the remaining js code with a syntax error - html tags are not valid js.